# c - setlocale() not working as expect

Tags: c, locale

The following program use `setlocale()` to take locale settings from environment variable, and print time.

**locale_test.c**:

```
// locale test

#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>

// locale test
void locale_test() {
    // use environment variable to get locale setting,
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    char buf[26];
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    ctime_r(&now, buf);
    printf("time: %s", buf);

    char *time_locale = setlocale(LC_TIME, NULL);
    printf("current LC_TIME locale: %s\n", time_locale);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    locale_test();
    return 0;
}
```

**Execute:**

- `LC_ALL=fr_FR LC_TIME=fr_FR ./a.out`, output is:

  > time: Wed Oct 14 13:16:35 2015
  >   current LC_TIME locale: C
- `LC_ALL=en_US LC_TIME=en_US ./a.out`, output is:

  > time: Wed Oct 14 13:17:12 2015
  >   current LC_TIME locale: C

**The question is:**

- The result of 2 execution are expected to be different format, due to different locale, but they are the same, why?
- When try to get current `LC_TIME`, it just print `C`, but not the value specified from environment variable.

---

**Update - Solution:**

According to comment & answer, following changes are made:

- Use correct locale name from result of `locale -a`
- Use `strftime()` to generate the time string instead of `ctime()`

The new program:

```
// locale test

#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>

// locale test
void locale_test() {
    // use environment variable to get locale setting,
    if(setlocale(LC_ALL, "") == NULL) {
        printf("error while setlocale()\n");
    }

    // get current LC_TIME
    char *time_locale = setlocale(LC_TIME, NULL);
    if(time_locale == NULL) {
        printf("error while setlocale()\n");
    } else {
        printf("LC_TIME: %s\n", time_locale);
    }

    // print time in locale,
    size_t buf_size = 50;
    char buf[buf_size];
    // char *format = "%F %T %z";
    char *format = "%A, %d %B %Y, %H:%M:%S %Z";

    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm_now;
    localtime_r(&now, &tm_now);

    strftime(buf, buf_size, format, &tm_now);
    printf("time: %s\n", buf);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    locale_test();
    return 0;
}
```

Then execute:

- `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 LC_TIME=en_US.utf8 ./a.out`, output is:

  > LC_TIME: en_US.utf8
  >   time: Wednesday, 14 October 2015, 16:36:36 CST
- `LC_ALL=zh_CN.utf8 LC_TIME=zh_CN.utf8 ./a.out`, output is:

  > LC_TIME: zh_CN.utf8
  >   time: 星期三, 14 十月 2015, 16:38:10 CST
- `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 LC_TIME=en_US.utf8 ./a.out`, output is:

  > LC_TIME: ja_JP.utf8
  >   time: 水曜日, 14 10月 2015, 16:40:05 CST

That's work as expect.

Comment: from setlocale manpage: "If locale is NULL, the current locale is only queried, not modified. " Unless I missed something, you are not changing the locale

Comment: @Guillaume Yes, that's about `NULL`, but the first line in `locale_test()` from above program pass `""` - empty string, which is mentioned in manual `If  locale is "", each part of the locale that should be modified is set according to the environment variables.` So, it will take settings from environment variable, which I set in shell when execute the program.

Comment: Ok yes I missed that, my bad.

Comment: do you get any error when using the command LC_TIME=en_US ? Usually you need to set the locale with quotes

Comment: @Guillaume There is not error tip, the way I used to set locale here is just the same as set a environment variable in shell. like `name=Eric`, then echo `$name`, only that here it only effect the program (or process) to be executed, not the shell.

Comment: I'm saying this because I've tried your program, and it works fine for me, however when I try setting LC_TIME with the wrong syntax, the program just displays C, like yours is doing, hence why I think there could be an error in setting LC_TIME. Try "export LC_TIME=en_US"

Comment: @Guillaume Nice tip. I tried `export LC_ALL=en_US`, then get warning `bash: warning: setlocale: LC_TIME: cannot change locale (en_US): No such file or directory
`, maybe there is some bug on the distribution or missing locale files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to check the return value of `setlocale`, because it will fail if the locale string is invalid, the locale you want is not installed, or some other reason.

```
if (setlocale(LC_ALL, "") == NULL) {
    puts("Unable to set locale");
}
```

You can check what locales are available with `locale -a`. Maybe you do have a French locale installed, but you have to set it with `fr_FR.utf8`.

Then again, `ctime` output does not depend on the locale; the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/asctime.html) specifies its exact format, and it will always be in English. For localized output use `strftime` instead.

Comment: Cool, using `locale -a` to figure out the exact name first did help to fix the second question, but for the first question I think some locale file is still missing, because I always see the same time format.

Comment: Ah yes, there's another thing: `ctime` always returns date in English, it does not use the current locale.

Comment: Nice, I use `strftime()` to replace `ctime()`, now it works well.